# Memory Management in Loading Images

Tags: objective-c, animation, memory-management, uiimageview

I have a panning gesture that pans across a series of images. I'm not sure how to correctly manage the memory for this, after panning for a certain length of time, I'm getting crashes.

animImage is a UIImageView;

Here is how it works:

```
- (IBAction) panAnim:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    CGPoint translate = [sender translationInView:sliderView];

    if (translate.x >= lastPoint) {
        difference = translate.x - lastPoint;
        [self forwardAnim:difference];
    } else {
        difference = lastPoint - translate.x;
        [self backwardAnim:difference];
    }
    lastPoint = translate.x;
}

-(void)forwardAnim:(CGFloat)speed{
    NSInteger newFrame = currentFrame+speed;
    currentFrame = newFrame;
    if (currentFrame>=totalFrames) {
        currentFrame=0;
    }
    NSString *newImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currentAnimation objectAtIndex:currentFrame]];  
    animImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:newImagePath];
}

-(void)backwardAnim:(CGFloat)speed{
    NSInteger newFrame = currentFrame-speed;
    currentFrame = newFrame;
    if (currentFrame<0) {
        currentFrame=(totalFrames-1);
    }
    NSString *newImagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currentAnimation objectAtIndex:currentFrame]];  
    animImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:newImagePath];
}
```

The animation detects position of the translate and calculates what 'frame' the animation should be at and then swaps out the image.

I'm getting a very smooth animation for this but obviously I'm causing a crash because I'm not managing the memory correctly. I'm getting Memory Warnings and then crashes - but only when I've been scrolling through the images for a while.

I need to figure out a way to pre-load 100 images at a time, so I can only keep the memory of 100 images. It's strange because the images are opened and closed properly in the IO Output in Instruments.

Thanks for your help!

Cheers, **D**

Comment: Is animImage an UIImageView? At first glance I don't see anything wrong with the code you've posted other than perhaps an index issue with currentAnimation. Do you get a stack trace?

Comment: yeah animImage is an UIImageView. If this code is fine then perhaps the cause of the crash is elsewhere. I'll investigate. Cheers

Comment: @j0k the cause of the issue is out of memory warnings and then crash - it IS because of the animation.

Comment: I don't see any problems in the code -- maybe try running it under Instruments to see what is leaking?

Comment: @Daniel - Probably not relevant, but worth checking, but how big are the images you're loading?

Comment: @j0k 25kb a piece and there's 200 of them. So 5Mb in total for the lot of them.

Comment: @Mike Morearty - according to instruments there were no leaks in memory. But I noticed in the Allocations box that the Living Allocations rose and rose as I scrolled through the animation, until it crashed. I'll post my log in the question.

Comment: This code seems ok. Which OS are you running? imageNamed: should take care of the caching, but you might want to try alloc/init/release instead. Keep in mind that memory usage is *not* what it is on disk but rather width*height*4byte.

Comment: Also, is there more info on the crash? Just because you get a memory warning doesn't mean you crash because of it. And there's more up to memory warnings than running out of memory, i.e. some views might get released etc.

Comment: I find that if I scroll through the images quickly - the physical memory used grows and grows until crash (instruments). You mean load the image into a separate object, alloc and init that object, assign it to the imageView and then release it?

Comment: I mean using [[UIImage alloc] init..] instead of the convenient imageNamed:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+[UIImageView imageNamed:]` caches the images it loads, so it's not surprising that your memory usage keeps increasing. You might try changing those `+imageNamed:` calls to `+imageWithContentsOfFile:` instead. That may hurt your animation performance, but I suspect you'll see memory usage drop significantly.

A memory warning doesn't mean that a crash is imminent. It'd help if you'd post the details of the crash. Looking at the crash log, you should be able to identify a line in your code that leads to the crash -- it may be a few frames from the top of the stack. Find that line, put a breakpoint a line or two before it, and step through the code imagining what could happen on each line that might cause a problem -- failed allocation, bad value, etc.

BTW, your 25kB image files likely expand to something much larger in memory.

Comment: this works. I've not got it to crash since I used this. I was not aware of the caching on `imageNamed:` - thank you! I'll award the bounty when it unlocks (21 hours)

Comment: Great, glad I could help. Still, make sure that you test thoroughly under low memory conditions -- your app shouldn't crash even if memory does get low. Switching to `+imageWithContentsOfFile:` is probably a beneficial change, but it may also mask your real problem by eliminating the low memory situation.

Comment: as it stands this is the only functionality on the app (I've yet to build a lot of it), so I'm not sure that it's masking a problem - I think this represents the only issue at the moment. Now this issue is fixed, I can proceed to build the rest of it

Comment: Bounty Awarded! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Daniel Hanly, I appreciate your appreciation. ;-) Thanks.